# Comapare Ienumerable<int> and List<Entity> and get matching ID's

Tags: c#, list, comparison, ienumerable

I have `Ienumerable<int> Temp1;` from DB

and other `List<entity> Temp2;` with properties **Id and name**.

I want to `compare Temp1 & Temp2(Id)` and find the matching Values and have it in a List.

What is the best way to implement this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need both name and Id in final list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var sameIds = Temp2.Select(x=>x.Id).Intersect(Temp1);
```

first Selecting only Id's to new `IEnumerable<int>` then intersecting it with currently available `IEnumerable<int>` will give you matching id's

Comment: The result will be of Type IEnumerable<int>? I think he need the collection of entities? is this correct

Comment: From this i can derive anything i need. Thanks

Comment: @User3805967 "ID alone will do" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var outp = (from temp1 in Temp1
            join temp2 in Temp2
            on temp1 equals temp2.Id
            select temp2).ToArray();
```

You can also use Let and use the ==.